# JsonMappingException while parsing List

Tags: java, json, list, exception

Here's the problem:

I've been trying to convert my Student object to JSON string, but looks like there is problem with converting List to a part of a JSON

My Student code is:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Student {

    @NonNull String id;
    @NonNull String name;
    @NonNull int age;
    @NonNull List<String> courses;
    int grade;
```

This is there the problem occurs:

```
ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();

public Student findStudent(String id) throws Exception {
    //finding a student
    Student student = repository.findById(id);
    student.setCourses(findCourses(student.getId()));
    //everything works fine here
    System.out.println(jackson.writeValueAsString(student)); //this is where error occurs
    return student;
}
```

The error output is:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (through reference chain: ru.tinkoff.tfpr.components.Student["courses"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Is there any clue how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I ran your code and everything works fine besides I am not sure the returned object of `findCourses(student.getId())`. BTW, `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will be automatically added  once you add `@Data`.